# Using socat to access API behind proxy with client certificate

Tags: bash, proxy, socat

Is it possible, to use socat to access an API via an external proxy, where the API needs client authentication?

Currently I only found out, how to access any website via proxy:

TCP4-LISTEN:8443,reuseaddr,fork TCP:example-proxy-server.com:3128

How can I add the API url (let's say my-api.com) authenticating via .pem file?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have enough StackExchange reputation but part of what you want to achieve can be done with:

socat openssl-connect:$HOST:$PORT,cert=client.pem,cafile=server.crt

Comment: now my reputation is -1. lol victim of it's own poison